# write an undefined behavior

Tags: popularity-contest

**Header:**
this question has a very close duplicate, but the other question requires a difference between versions of the languages, instead of a difference between different implementation. this means that ***all*** answers from the almost-duplicate are invlid here.
 this is also my first question, so please don't be harsh.

## the question:

in this challenge you will be writing code that runs differently on at least two different implementations of your language, such as jython / ironPython for python. different versions of the same implementation don't count.

your code should be runnable on all existing implementations (code that doesn't compile on one implementation or halts with an error isn't valid).
your code should be well-defined in the scope of each one of the implementations you chose (your code should always do the same thing when run on the same implementation, even on different computers/OS's etc.)
also, code isn't allowed to check the implementation directly.

this is a popularity contest so try to be creative, most upvoted answer wins.

Comment: you should specify that endianness isn't a valid difference. it would be trivial to submit a dozen examples in different low[ish] level languages that differ in output due to byte ordering.

Comment: @Sparr doesn't the requirement that the program will run the same on different computers/os's eliminate this?

Comment: oh, good point. I guess I was thinking of platform differences rather than language implementation differences.

Comment: But this question has a dramatically different scoring

Comment: This question invites a completely different kind of answers - instead of short answers, creative and surprising answers

Comment: I don't believe it's [different enough](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/777/14215), since answers could literally be copied directly from the other question.

Comment: @Geobits  actually not, because this question doesn't count different versions as different implementations

Comment: *Your code should be well-defined in the scope of each one of the implementations you chose.* That's not undefined behavior. The outcome of undefined behavior may depend on the version, the compiler flags, the weather condition or who won the last Super Bowl. What your looking for is called **implementation-defined behavior**.

Comment: @Dennis if so, what do you think i should change the title to?

Comment: *Invoke implementation-defined behavior* perhaps? Or *It works, but not as I thought it would*. I personally like *Why are you doing this to me, Internet Explorer?*, but that might be too specific to JavaScript...

Comment: FWIW I voted to close not as duplicate but as "Unclear what you're asking". The question of whether two implementations are "*the same*" for the purpose of this question seems to be about as answerable as the old "*How many angels can dance on the head of a pin?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## C++

This should print `6.28319` on all *compliant* compilers of C++..and `3.14159` for the Visual C++ compiler.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#if compl-1 
#define oddNewPi =6.28318530718,compl
#else
#define twoPlusTwoIsFive
#endif
int main(int twoPlusTwoIsFive, char **warIsPeace){
    double goodOlPi = -3.14159265359,
    bitand oddNewPi = goodOlPi;

    int J = 42;
    float k = (compl+J)/-40.0f;

    goodOlPi *= -1;
    if(k > 1.0f){
        twoPlusTwoIsFive oddNewPi *= compl-3;
    }

    std::cout << goodOlPi << std::endl;
}
```

How this works: `compl` is equivalent to the operator `~`, thus, `compl-1` is `0`. However, for the Visual C++ compiler, `compl` is not treated as an operator (if you include `<ciso686>`, then it is a macro that expands to `~`), therefore, `#if compl-1` is treated as `#if 0-1`, or `#if -1`.

`bitand` is equivalent to `&`, but in the code here, the Visual C++ compiler treats it as a variable name instead.

When `compl-1` evaluates as false, the code expands to

```c++
#include <iostream>
int main(int, char **warIsPeace){
    double goodOlPi = -3.14159265359,
          &oddNewPi = goodOlPi;

    int J = 42;
    // equal to 43/40.0f
    float k = (~ +J)/-40.0f;

    goodOlPi *= -1;
    if(k > 1.0f){ // always true
        oddNewPi *= ~ -3; // equal to two
    }

    // prints 6.28319
    std::cout << goodOlPi << std::endl;
}
```

whereas if `compl-1` evaluates as true, the code expands to

```c++
#include <iostream>
int main(int twoPlusTwoIsFive, char **warIsPeace){
    double goodOlPi = -3.14159265359,
           bitand   = 6.28318530718,
           compl    = goodOlPi;

    int J = 42;
    // equal to (-3.1415.. + 42)/-40.0f: about -1
    float k = (compl + J)/-40.0f;

    goodOlPi *= -1;
    if(k > 1.0f){ // always false
        twoPlusTwoIsFive = 6.28318530718, compl *= compl - 3;
    }

    // prints 3.14159
    std::cout << goodOlPi << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6)

In ES5 and possibly older versions, prefixing a number with `0x` would cause the number to be treated as hexadecimal.

In ES6, prefixing a number with `0b` causes the number to treated as binary.

The `Number` constructor attempts to evaluate the argument as a number and if it is unable to do so, returns `NaN`. For strings, the [evaluation syntax](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type) describes a positive/negative sign with decimal digits OR `0x` followed by hexadecimal digits (optionally surrounded by whitespace). The JavaScript engine in Firefox and Chrome appear to have different implementations when a string is passed beginning with `0b`:

#### Firefox 32

```
Number('11'); // 11
Number('011'); // 11
Number('0b11'); // NaN
Number('0x11'); // 17

Number(11); // 11
Number(011); // 9
Number(0b11); // 3
Number(0x11); // 17
```

#### Chrome 37

```
Number('11'); // 11
Number('011'); // 11
Number('0b11'); // 3
Number('0x11'); // 17

Number(11); // 11
Number(011); // 9
Number(0b11); // 3
Number(0x11); // 17
```

I'm assuming that the Chromium dev team will fix the bug sooner or later, but these are the latest stable versions of the browsers at this point in time.

Neither Node.js nor Internet Explorer's JavaScript implementation supports this feature of ES6, so it would not be fair to test on those platforms.

I should also note that the ES6 specification is still a draft, so perhaps strings beginning with "0b" may be allowed in the evaluation syntax some time in the future.

Comment: I'd rather have the change the spec. `Number('0b11')` looks pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

### C++

I'm not sure this is exactly what the question asked for, but this came up as a side-question in an interview once:

```
#include <iostream>

#define f(a, b) a * b

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 3;

    std::cout << f(i++, i++) << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

VC++ returns the answer as `3 * 3 = 9`. [compileonline.com](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php) (which uses g++) returns the answer as `3 * 4 = 12` (those are all the compilers I have access to right now). I can't imagine that there's any more possible answers than those two. Try it out for yourself and see what you get!

Comment: @may i ask what part of the spec is unclear?

Comment: You didn't mention anything about using different compilers of the same language.

Comment: a compiler is an implementation

Comment: That's actual undefined behavior, so while `9` and `12` may sound like the two sensible outcomes, the compiler is allowed to do *anything* in this case.